# What's the name of this slow cooking technique?

Tags: slow-cooking

I just discovered the joy of slow cooking meat, separating the juice, then boiling it to a reduction, then simmering the meat in its own concentrated juices (with some other tasty ingredients added).

So is there a name for simmering slow cooked meat in its concentrated juices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be what I would call stewing.  From the [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stewing):

"A dish cooked by stewing, especially a mixture of meat or fish and vegetables with stock."

I suppose you could also coin your own, new term call "modified-reduction-stewing."  Oh, wait, that's mine!  Make up your own ;--)

Comment: modified-reduction-stewing => mo-re-stew => more stew

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like braising, though while it's traditional to concentrate the juices afterward, it's optionally delicious to throw everything back in to simmer in them.

Braising is a pretty general term though: it also applies to slow cooking in any concentrated juices, or even un-concentrated juices (though this is not recommended for best results).

Comment: What do you mean throw everything back in? You mean for leftovers?

Comment: I looked up the definition of braising--close! but not it. Braising requires the food to be cooked in dry heat first (ie browning the outside of a roast) then simmered in a liquid.

Answer (score -1):

This process is called confit.  It is a french term meaning 'cooked in own juices'.

Comment: Confit does not mean "cooked in own juices", on the contrary it is used for food which is preserved by submerging it in fat (for meat) or sugar syrup (for fruit)

Answer (score -3):

are you talking about sous vide?